# Environments nested in fullwidth

Tags: memoir, tcolorbox, multicol, fullwidth

I'm struggling to find a way to set up some fullwidth text in my memoir document. This is an extract of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}                        %document class
\setstocksize{240mm}{150mm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                            %font output
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         %font input
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAGE LAYOUT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{geometry}

\let\footruleskip\undefined                         %headings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\nouppercaseheads

\settrimmedsize{240mm}{150mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{193mm}{84mm}{*}
\setulmargins{27mm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{18mm}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{3mm}{3.5cm}{\onelineskip}
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{\onelineskip}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.2cm}
%\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\addtolength{\footskip}{0.55cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FULLWIDTH
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[outermargin=-3.5cm]{fullwidth}

\newenvironment{fullwidthblocked}{%
\blockmargin%
\begin{fullwidth}%
}{%
\end{fullwidth}%
\unblockmargin%
}
```

Writing a long paragraph inside of a `fullwidthblocked` environment does not bring any problems: the text starts where it should start and breaks correctly when the page finishes. For example, this code works:

```
\begin{document}

\lipsum[99]

\begin{fullwidthblocked}
\lipsum
\end{fullwidthblocked}

\end{document}
```

However, I can not figure out a way to correctly put other environments in a `fullwidthblocked`. I tried with a `tcolorbox` and a `multicols` with two columns, but with terrible results. If the text is too long, the `tcolorbox` starts in a new page, breaks off in the middle of the page and restarts in a new page, while inserting a `multicols` keeps the code from compiling.

If needed, I can provide you with some more explicit examples.

Comment: Have you tried `tcolorbox` with the `breakable` option?

Comment: Yes, I use this code to put a `tcolorbox` inside the `fullwidthblocked`:

`\begin{fullwidthblocked}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw, breakable, left=1.5mm, right=1.5mm]%%
•
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{fullwidthblocked}`

Comment: I solved the problem using the package `mdframed` and calling the option `outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax`.